# Limiting amount of common nodes in a relationship - Neo4j

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

Say I have a nodes person and movie with a relation of [likes]. I am trying to be able to limit the amount of persons that like the same movie without limiting my results to only include 1 movie.

For example:

```
    MATCH (p:Person)-[LIKES]->(m:Movie)
    WHERE
    p.age < 30
    p.gender = "Male"
    RETURN p,m
```

So in the query above I would like to get all the results but filter them so that only 2 Persons will like the same movie.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want ... for each movie, you want to return two persons that liked it ?

Comment: I want to limit my results to only have two people like liked the same movie. But I don't want to limit my results to only contain one movie.

So basically I want to get all the results from above but filter them down to only include at most two persons that liked the same movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This knowledge base article goes over different ways to [limit match results per row](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/limiting-match-results-per-row/).

For a non-APOC approach you can get the slice of the collection of people who liked the movie:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIKES]->(m:Movie)
WHERE
p.age < 30
p.gender = "Male"
RETURN m, collect(p)[..2] as peopleWhoLiked
```

If you want a separate row per person, then UNWIND the `peopleWhoLiked` list before the return.

For the second approach, you'll need APOC Procedures.

In order to use LIMIT, you'll need to first match on all movies, then perform the limited match to :Person nodes using `apoc.cypher.run()`.

Answer (score 1):

To get all movies that have exactly two (under-30 male) likers:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIKES]->(m:Movie)
WHERE
  p.age < 30 AND
  p.gender = "Male"
WITH m, COLLECT(p) AS likers
WHERE SIZE(likers) = 2
RETURN m, likers;
```

Comment: So I didn't necessarily want to limit my results to movies that had exactly 2 likers but I wanted to only return at most two likers of a common movie. But this definitely still helps me get closer to that.